# Obtain sigma of gaussian blur between two images

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Suppose I have an image `A`, I applied Gaussian Blur on it with `Sigam=3` So I got another Image `B`. Is there a way to know the applied sigma if A,B is given?

**Further clarification:**

Image A:

[image: Orignal Image]

Image B:

[image]

I want to write a function that take `A,B` and return `Sigma`:

```
double get_sigma(cv::Mat const& A,cv::Mat const& B);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Stupid solution: The function could apply the gaussian blur with different sigma values to image A and compare the result with image B pixel-by-pixel. But you would have to limit the sigma values to check, e.g. to 3, 5 and 7. But maybe this is sufficient in your case?

Comment: Thanks. It is right and not stupid. it could be turned into optimization problem and try to minimize the difference relativity to sigma but the problem is that I need some accuracy so i will depend on sigma not the win size. Sigma is continuous one which make the process is a bit slow.

Comment: Right, I was thinking about the window size (3, 5, 7).. I guess the problem is that by applying a blur you are loosing information which is why you cannot "reverse calculate" and retrieve the sigma value used.

Comment: Have a look on the internet at `deconvolution` and `Wiener deconvolution`. You can probably recover your sigma from that

Comment: @Miki Thanks, from very fast reading, I saw that this kind of process is applied for referenceless image. In my case I have the query and the reference, do not you think there is a bit eaiser way? or I am wrong ?

Comment: You can probably simplify stuff, knowing original image. But I don't know, actually. It was just to give you some pointers.

Comment: Got it. many thanks:) @Miki

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT1:** ***The suggested approach doesn't work in practice in its original form(i.e. using only 9 equations for a `3 x 3` kernel), and I realized this later. See EDIT1 below for an explanation and EDIT2 for a method that works.***

**EDIT2:** ***As suggested by Humam, I used the Least Squares Estimate (LSE) to find the coefficients.***

I think you can estimate the filter kernel by solving a linear system of equations in this case. A linear filter weighs the pixels in a window by its coefficients, then take their sum and assign this value to the center pixel of the window in the result image. So, for a `3 x 3` filter like

[image: kernel]

the resulting pixel value in the filtered image

```
result_pix_value = h11 * a(y, x) + h12 * a(y, x+1) + h13 * a(y, x+2) +
                   h21 * a(y+1, x) + h22 * a(y+1, x+1) + h23 * a(y+1, x+2) +
                   h31 * a(y+2, x) + h32 * a(y+2, x+1) + h33 * a(y+2, x+2)
```

where `a's` are the pixel values within the window in the original image. Here, for the `3 x 3` filter you have 9 unknowns, so you need 9 equations. You can obtain those 9 equations using 9 pixels in the resulting image. Then you can form an `Ax = b` system and solve for x to obtain the filter coefficients. With the coefficients available, I think you can find the sigma.

In the following example I'm using non-overlapping windows as shown to obtain the equations.
[image: wins]

You don't have to know the size of the filter. If you use a larger size, the coefficients that are not relevant will be close to zero.

Your result image size is different than the input image, so i didn't use that image for following calculation. I use your input image and apply my own filter.

I tested this in Octave. You can quickly run it if you have Octave/Matlab. For Octave, you need to load the image package.

I'm using the following kernel to blur the image:

```
h =

   0.10963   0.11184   0.10963
   0.11184   0.11410   0.11184
   0.10963   0.11184   0.10963
```

When I estimate it using a window size 5, I get the following. As I said, the coefficients that are not relevant are close to zero.

```
g =

  9.5787e-015  -3.1508e-014  1.2974e-015  -3.4897e-015  1.2739e-014
  -3.7248e-014  1.0963e-001  1.1184e-001  1.0963e-001  1.8418e-015
  4.1825e-014  1.1184e-001  1.1410e-001  1.1184e-001  -7.3554e-014
  -2.4861e-014  1.0963e-001  1.1184e-001  1.0963e-001  9.7664e-014
  1.3692e-014  4.6182e-016  -2.9215e-014  3.1305e-014  -4.4875e-014
```

**EDIT1:**
First of all, my apologies.

- This approach doesn't really work in the practice. I've used the `filt = conv2(a, h, 'same');` in the code. The resulting image data type in this case is double, whereas in the actual image the data type is usually `uint8`, so there's loss of information, which we can think of as noise. I simulated this with the minor modification `filt = floor(conv2(a, h, 'same'));`, and then I don't get the expected results.
- The sampling approach is not ideal, because it's possible that it results in a degenerated system. Better approach is to use random sampling, avoiding the borders and making sure the entries in the b vector are unique. In the ideal case, as in my code, we are making sure the system `Ax = b` has a unique solution this way.
- One approach would be to reformulate this as `Mv = 0` system and try to minimize the squared norm of `Mv` under the constraint `squared-norm v = 1`, which we can solve using SVD. I could be wrong here, and I haven't tried this.
- Another approach is to use the symmetry of the Gaussian kernel. Then a `3x3` kernel will have only 3 unknowns instead of 9. I think, this way we impose additional constraints on `v` of the above paragraph.
- I'll try these out and post the results, even if I don't get the expected results.

**EDIT2:**

- Using the LSE, we can find the filter coefficients as `pinv(A'A)A'b`. For completion, I'm adding a simple (and slow) LSE code.

Initial Octave Code:

```
clear all

im = double(imread('I2vxD.png'));

k = 5;
r = floor(k/2);

a = im(:, :, 1);  % take the red channel
h = fspecial('gaussian', [3 3], 5); % filter with a 3x3 gaussian
filt = conv2(a, h, 'same');

% use non-overlapping windows to for the Ax = b syatem
% NOTE: boundry error checking isn't performed in the code below
s = floor(size(a)/2);
y = s(1);
x = s(2);

w = k*k;
y1 = s(1)-floor(w/2) + r;
y2 = s(1)+floor(w/2);
x1 = s(2)-floor(w/2) + r;
x2 = s(2)+floor(w/2);

b = [];
A = [];
for y = y1:k:y2
  for x = x1:k:x2
    b = [b; filt(y, x)];
    f = a(y-r:y+r, x-r:x+r);
    A = [A; f(:)'];
  end
end

% estimated filter kernel
g = reshape(A\b, k, k)
```

LSE method:

```
clear all

im = double(imread('I2vxD.png'));

k = 5;
r = floor(k/2);

a = im(:, :, 1);  % take the red channel
h = fspecial('gaussian', [3 3], 5); % filter with a 3x3 gaussian
filt = floor(conv2(a, h, 'same'));

s = size(a);
y1 = r+2; y2 = s(1)-r-2;
x1 = r+2; x2 = s(2)-r-2;

b = [];
A = [];

for y = y1:2:y2
  for x = x1:2:x2
    b = [b; filt(y, x)];
    f = a(y-r:y+r, x-r:x+r);
    f = f(:)';
    A = [A; f];
  end
end

g = reshape(A\b, k, k) % A\b returns the least squares solution
%g = reshape(pinv(A'*A)*A'*b, k, k)
```

Comment: simple, tidy, cleaver and straightforward.. much appreciated sir

Comment: @HumamHelfawi I just realized that this won't work. Really sorry! See my edit for the explanation. I'll check how to fix this -if that's possible- and post as soon as I find something. Hope you haven't tried this with opencv yet.

Comment: No problem for me at all. I would not use the implemnetation ypu provided becuase I will implement it myself using C++ & OpenCV. Furhter more I will not just take random 9 points I will use Batch LSE or RANSAC with all the points. So what you have proposed is perfectly fit for me.. Thanks again